# Different behaviour when using poly() inside versus outside lm() in R

Tags: r, linear-regression, lm, polynomials

Here is some code that fits a polynomial to data and plots it:

```
x <- c(30, 47.1, 69.6, 93.8, 117, 139.1, 170.9, 189.4, 197.5, 212.4)
y <- c(0, 1.734, 5.181, 9.026, 12.837, 16.197, 21.603, 25.306, 26.942, 29.384)
plot(y ~ x)
mod <- lm(y ~ poly(x, 2, raw = TRUE))
pred <- predict(mod, data.frame(x = 40:200))
lines(40:200, pred)
```

[image]

When I try to do exactly the same thing, but using an intermediate variable to store the results of `poly()`, I get an error:

```
x <- c(30, 47.1, 69.6, 93.8, 117, 139.1, 170.9, 189.4, 197.5, 212.4)
y <- c(0, 1.734, 5.181, 9.026, 12.837, 16.197, 21.603, 25.306, 26.942, 29.384)
plot(y ~ x)
p <- poly(x, 2, raw = TRUE)
mod <- lm(y ~ p)
pred <- predict(mod, data.frame(x = 40:200))
lines(40:200, pred)
```

Error message:

```
> pred <- predict(mod, data.frame(x = 40:200))
Warning message:
'newdata' had 161 rows but variables found have 10 rows 
> lines(40:200, pred)
Error in xy.coords(x, y) : 'x' and 'y' lengths differ
```

Why is this happening?

Comment: `poly` is a function on its own giving you a polygon. Inside `lm`, `poly` is a formula.